# Some services causes slower boot time Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot, 17.10

My laptop takes very long time to boot, I think some services takes more time to load. 
 
I don't know should I disable it or not.

Result of systemd-analyze blame

```
         36.896s dev-sda1.device
         27.033s systemd-udevd.service
          8.983s lvm2-monitor.service
          8.489s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          4.846s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          4.317s snapd.service
          3.406s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          3.354s keyboard-setup.service
          3.136s libvirtd.service
          2.934s fwupd.service
          2.641s systemd-journal-flush.service
          2.522s vmware-USBArbitrator.service
          2.322s vmware.service
          1.802s gpu-manager.service
          1.387s plymouth-start.service
          1.132s systemd-rfkill.service
          1.116s NetworkManager.service
          1.105s apparmor.service
          1.089s grub-common.service
          1.056s udisks2.service
          1.055s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.040s ModemManager.service
          1.012s ebtables.service
          1.007s plymouth-read-write.service
           988ms networking.service
           956ms preload.service
           860ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           859ms dev-hugepages.mount
           857ms dev-mqueue.mount
           842ms accounts-daemon.service
           683ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
           595ms rsyslog.service
           593ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           568ms lm-sensors.service
           528ms systemd-journald.service
           518ms mnt-63137fb2\x2ddb1d\x2d4b9a\x2d96f7\x2d16e6a2d7c030.mount
           483ms avahi-daemon.service
           451ms vboxdrv.service
           444ms systemd-sysctl.service
           441ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-593ebe45\x2da387\x2d4d82\x2db1
           325ms teamviewerd.service
           324ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           321ms smbd.service
           290ms thermald.service
           289ms home.mount
           282ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
           281ms binfmt-support.service
           275ms ssh.service
           248ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           209ms wpa_supplicant.service
           208ms systemd-random-seed.service
           208ms ufw.service
           143ms systemd-resolved.service
           130ms nmbd.service
           126ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           106ms packagekit.service
            87ms upower.service
            76ms gdm.service
            74ms snap-skype-23.mount
            55ms snap-skype-19.mount
            54ms polkit.service
            50ms user@1000.service
            45ms bluetooth.service
            44ms apport.service
            41ms systemd-logind.service
            39ms snap-core-4206.mount
            38ms speech-dispatcher.service
            38ms snap-skype-22.mount
            37ms setvtrgb.service
            27ms user@121.service
            26ms snapd.socket
            24ms snap-core-4110.mount
            21ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            21ms kerneloops.service
            20ms pppd-dns.service
            20ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
            17ms alsa-restore.service
            13ms smartmontools.service
            13ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a7b74ce7\x2d3b47\x2d4848\x2dad82\x2d988c908
            12ms colord.service
            10ms rtkit-daemon.service
             9ms libvirt-guests.service
             9ms qemu-kvm.service
             9ms dev-loop2.device
             9ms dev-loop1.device
             8ms vsftpd.service
             8ms dev-loop0.device
             8ms dns-clean.service
             7ms ureadahead-stop.service
             6ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             6ms console-setup.service
             5ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
             5ms nvidia-persistenced.service
             4ms vboxautostart-service.service
             3ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
             3ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
             3ms vboxweb-service.service
             2ms dev-loop4.device
             2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             2ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             1ms dev-loop3.device
```

Result of systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
graphical.target @54.779s
└─multi-user.target @54.778s
  └─vmware.service @52.455s +2.322s
    └─network-online.target @52.449s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @43.958s +8.489s
        └─NetworkManager.service @42.841s +1.116s
          └─dbus.service @42.832s
            └─basic.target @42.832s
              └─sockets.target @42.832s
                └─snapd.socket @42.805s +26ms
                  └─sysinit.target @42.791s
                    └─apparmor.service @41.686s +1.105s
                      └─local-fs.target @41.681s
                        └─run-user-121-gvfs.mount @53.549s
                          └─run-user-121.mount @45.912s
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @36.611s
                              └─systemd-remount-fs.service @36.463s +126ms
                                └─system.slice @3.986s
                                  └─-.slice @3.984s
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: How long is a "long time to boot"?

Comment: Almost one and half minute